# return floats and int in a string of mixed input python

Tags: python, regex, int

I'm trying to create a function that will return intigers and floats from strings inputted. but will remove words containing any non-numerical characters. Currently I've gotten it to return only numbers but it's not returning the floats as floats

```
float_sort=0.2 2.1 3.1 ab 3 c abc23
float_sort = "".join(re.findall(r"d+\.\\d+|\d+", float_sort))

#Actual results 2,2,1,3,1,3,2,3
#desired results: 0.2,2.1,3.1,3
```

Comment: operator precedence dictates that your `|` does not act on what you think it does.

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all. In your regex you seem to have messed up backslashes in the first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
re.findall(r"\b(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\b", float_sort)
```

It uses the `\b` boundary class, and you were double escaping with `\\`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

The regex matches a space-separated word with only numeric characters and possibly a single dot. Then convert everything to `float`, then convert the ones that could be represented as `int` to `int`. The last step is only necessary if you really need those numbers to be `int` for some reason.

```
import re

float_sort = '0.2 2.1 3.1 ab 3 c abc23'
split = re.findall(r"\b(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\b", float_sort)
print(float_sort)

split = [float(x) for x in split]
split = [int(x) if x == int(x) else x for x in split]

print(split)
print([type(x) for x in split])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each value and try and convert it to a `float` or an int.  If we can't convert it, then we don't include it in our final output.  Strings have some useful functions that allow us to determine if the string could possibly represent an `int` or a `float`.

```
 # split each element on the space
 l = float_sort.split()

 # for each element, try and convert it to a float
 # and add it into the `converted` list
 converted = []
 for i in l:
    try:
       # check if the string is all numeric.  In that case, it can be an int
       # otherwise, it could be a float     
       if i.isnumeric():
           converted.append(int(i))
       else:
         converted.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
       pass

  # [0.2, 2.1, 3.1, 3]
```